# Settings.System.VOLUME_SETTINGS removed in Android API 23?

Tags: android, settings, system, volume

It looks like android.provider.Settings.System.VOLUME_SETTINGS field has been removed from Android SDK. I can't find any information about it but the app won't compile with sdk version set to 23. Also on developer.android.com thi field is missing. In cached version of the page it is present however. Can anybody confirm this?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, I can't confirm it, but there was some scamware going around on the internet, which play adult content at full volume and you couldn't turn off the sound because the app was setting the volume to maximum every single millisecond, and it only went away if you entered a Paysafecard code or so. As a developer, I'd also remove that. But it's just a theory by me, so wait for people who know it for sure.

Comment: They also have removed all the volume settings. I have no idea how to retrieve the volume of the alarm now.

Answer (score 0):

The volume settings are still there, but they are no longer exposed. They are just strings, however, and so if you are using getUriFor() you could just pass the string that you see in the Android code.

Ref: [android.provider.Settings](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/provider/Settings.java?av=f#2187)